# Does ComponentMeasurements and MorphologicalComponents label the components identically

Tags: image-processing, implementation-details

1. `MorphologicalComponents[image]` returns array in which each pixel of *image* is replaced by an integer index representing the connected foreground image component in which the pixel lies.
2. `ComponentMeasurements[image,"prop"]` uses the connectivity of nonzero pixels in image to compute the label matrix
3. `ComponentMeasurements[m,"prop"]` computes the values of property prop for each component of a label matrix m that consists of identical elements.

So, in case 1 and 3, I expect, and from explanation in 3, its seems obvious that the indices (labels), and ordering in list, are same for the same components,
**but** in case when comparing 1 and 2, can we definitely suppose that these indices (labels), and ordering in list, are sam for same components?

Comment: Perhaps try an example on an image?

Comment: I tryed, on some samples, but how can I be sure that these are not coincidences. I would like to know for general explanation.

Comment: I don't have a proof, but have been using this kind of functions since years. I never have seen any inconsistency of the labeling here. If you specifiy the `CornerNeighbors` option, it of course must be set consistently. The only case of inconsistency I can imagine is if you have a personal way to compute the labeling to obtain `m` using some different order (e.g. colum-wise; `MorphologicalComponents` uses a row-wise scheme, i.e. scan line order) to search for the labels, then of course you cannot assume consistency.